# Which file permission to write to text files?

Tags: php, ftp, chmod

my PHP script writes to text.txt files such

```
 $filename = "pref.enc";  // TEXT FILE
    $file_content = file($filename); 
    $x = count($file_content); 
    $fp = fopen($filename, "w+");  
$file_content[0] = "$my_station" . "\n";
    $y = 0; 
    while($y < $x) 
    { 
    fwrite($fp, $file_content[$y]); 
    $y++; 
    } 
    fclose($fp);
```

Which CHMOD permission is recommended for text files **AND folder** (the folder holds the text files)?

755 or 777 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- 0755 for directories
- 0644 for files

See [chmod](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod)

This is assuming that you want everybody to read it.